# Expansion around a singular point of a multivalued meromorphic function (due to Riemann/Cauchy)

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, ho.history-overview, riemann-surfaces

In Riemann's publication about Abelian functions
'Theorie der Abelschen Functionen' ([Here the original paper in german](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG2wF.png))
at the end of Chapter 4, part 2 is clamed that for every Riemann
surface $T$ and $ a \in T$ every
meromorphic multivalued (?) function $f: T \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$
with $f(a)= \infty$ can be locally expanded via

$$g + A \cdot \log \ r +B r^{-1}+ C r^{-2}+ \ldots $$

where $g$ is *finite & continuous* in $a$ (so 'nice' enough), the values $A, B, C,\ldots$ are appropriate complex coefficients and the function $r: T \to \mathbb{C}$ is the so called
*infinitely small function of first order*. In modern language of complex analysis this $r$ is nothing but the local parameter in $a$, that is
locally near a point $a \in T$ the function $r$ behaves
like $z$ near $0$ on the plane $\mathbb{C}$. So for sake of simplicity say $T= \mathbb{C}$ and $f: \mathbb{C} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is multivalued with $f(0)= \infty$.

Why locally $f$ can be always writen as

$$ g(z) + A \cdot \log \ z +B z^{-1}+ C z^{-2}+ \ldots $$

with $g(z)$ finite in $0$ and continuous?

Riemann wrote that this ensues from known theorems on expansions of functions in power series due to Cauchy.

Unfortunately I nowhere in literature found a result on this kind of expansion. Does anybody know it? Especially the presence of $\log z$ confuses me. In this expansion $\log z$
is the only term which is multivalued and the existence of such expansion near $0$ suggests that every kind of multivaluedness of a function with $f(0)= \infty$ can be 'absorbed' by $\log z$, that's strange and I never saw such result in any book.

From modern complex analysis it is known that there are for meromorphic
functions three kinds of singularities: the removable one, pole of finite order and the essential singularity.
And in any modern book on complex analysis no one of these
three kinds of singularities is associated with an expansion
containing the $\log z $ term. Does anybody know the ancient result by Cauchy to which Riemann refer here and has it a modern analogue?

Here the relevant translated excerpt from Riemann's paper:

[image]

Comment: I repeat my advise:  learn the basic notions from some modern Complex variables book, and only AFTER that read Riemann. His terminology and the manner of exposition are out of date. Once you have some experience with the subject, it is easy to translate what he says to the modern language. Riemann did not write for the beginners. And his terminology is outdated. It is not an easy reading for a modern student.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: maybe I'm running to overestimate my knowledge on this topic, but
I think that the most principles which one can look up
in a basic modern complex variables book are at least roughly
familar to me. So I know at least basic notions. 
About the advise you gave me in my last question here
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386700/infinitely-small-functions-of-first-order-and-logarithm-of-abelian-functions-due
you are right, that was almost basic. A local parameter on 
a RS is exactly what Riemanns calls infinitely small function 
of first order.

Comment: But concerning *this* question I don't agree with you. I looked 
in several books on this topic and I nowhere found a
treating of the problem I described above. Honestly, I don't think that
this treating of the singularity using expansion containing 
this log term & it's meaning there is standard and something 'that 
can be easy translated in modern language'. If you think that
I wrong then I would appreciate if you could give a hint *where* I could look up it.

Comment: Perhaps, in context, he has reason to assume the derivative of the function is single-valued (and has no essential singularity)? Then the derivative would have a Laurent series expansion, which, integrating, would give an expansion of this form.

Comment: @Will Sawin: That's a good suggestion, possibly I 
somewhere overlooked that Riemann maybe somewhere explicitely
assumed that he deals *only* with multi-valued
functions with single-valued derivative.

I don't know the historical background but possibly 
Riemann studied during his lifetime
when he 'invented' Riemann surfaces 
*only* multi-valued
functions with single-valued derivative, 
I don't known, but of course the expansion above make 
is always given *only* with multi-valued
functions with single-valued derivative.

Comment: I found the answer: In previous subpart of his Part I in the quoted
paper Riemann shortly remarks that he want to deal with
*single-valued functions on RS $T$ with isolated singularities (so moromorphics $T \to P^1$)
*and their integrals* (!) That's why $log \ r$ term in the series
may occure which confused me.

Comment: Please include some reference where we can see the context and statement of this theorem.

Comment: @DrPotato: The only googleble free available version is the original paper
'Theorie der Abel'schen Functionen'. See there page 17 at the end of
first subchapter of 'Erste Abtheilung'.